# Dynamically add machines in spark stage

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-virtual-machine

I am using spark standalone cluster version **2.3.0** running on Azure VMs.
The spark job has 5 stage processing. I want to add more machines for compute processing after stage 0.

At the moment, I am checking the spark api for stage completion.

Is there a feature or property in Spark **2.3.0** that can be enabled ??

Answer (score 0):

In spark on Yarn you can enable dynamic allocation via following settings

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled     
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors
spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors
```

If you refer to spark configuration page:
Dynamic Resource Allocation
Spark provides a mechanism to dynamically adjust the resources your application occupies based on the workload. This means that your application may give resources back to the cluster if they are no longer used and request them again later when there is demand. This feature is particularly useful if multiple applications share resources in your Spark cluster.
This feature is disabled by default and available on all coarse-grained cluster managers, i.e. standalone mode, YARN mode, and Mesos coarse-grained mode.

Link to documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/job-scheduling.html#configuration-and-setup

There are two requirements for using this feature. First, your application must set spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled to true. Second, you must set up an external shuffle service on each worker node in the same cluster and set spark.shuffle.service.enabled to true in your application.

I not sure on Azure how easy this is handled, here is a question about dynamic resources on EMR, not directly related but could help you in your searching.
[Spark + EMR using Amazon's "maximizeResourceAllocation" setting does not use all cores/vcores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003759/spark-emr-using-amazons-maximizeresourceallocation-setting-does-not-use-all)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, 
I have only 1 spark job running and its a stand alone application. Dynamic Resource Allocation is possible on YARN, not on standalone.

Secondly, for this dynamic allocation, I need to keep my spark machines UP and running until my stage processing is completes, this attract cost.

So, What I want is "Start VMs only when Spark Stage 0 processing is complete".